# Access dynamically added Component in Unity3d C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

After adding a `Component` to a `GameObject` via the `GameObject.AddComponent` method, how can I access this `Component` from another script?

---

here is myScript code (not attach to a GameObject):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MyScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public string       myName = "myName";
    public Vector3      pos;
    public bool         visible;
}
```

and here is the main code attached to a gameobject in the scene:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Main : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject cube;

    void Update() {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
            cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
            cube.AddComponent<MyScript>();
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift)) {
            var a = GameObject.Find("Cube");

            print("cube name/visible: " + 
            /* here is the problem, how do i access the MyScript variables? */ 
            a.myName + "/" + a.visible);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sure many are wondering `What your code looks like` also read [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) here

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking here. 
Do you mean "How can I access a dynamically added component from a separate script?"

Comment: I posted the code bellow, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To access a `Component` from a Unity3d `GameObject`, you should use the [`GameObject.GetComponent<T>()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) method. There is more than one way to do this.

```
MyScript m = gameObject.GetComponent<MyScript>();
MyScript m = gameObject.GetComponent("MyScript") as MyScript;
MyScript m = (MyScript) gameObject.GetComponent(typeof(MyScript));
```

From your example code, there are a few things that should really be addressed:

- If you want to create components in your scene dynamically, it is better practice to create a prefab, then add that into your scene
- If you are planning to add large amounts of objects into your scene at runtime, you should use pooling, rather than expensive creating and destroying objects
- `GameObject.Find("Cube");` will only find a single object named "Cube" in the heirarchy. You should use `FindObjectsOfType<MyScript>()` if you want to find all `GameObjects` that have the `MyScript` component (`FindObjectOfType` if you only want to find 1)

Based on that, you can get to the variables of `MyScript` like this:

```
MyScript a = FindObjectOfType<MyScript>();
print(a.myName + "/" + a.visible);
```

or if you want to check the status of all `MyScript` active components:

```
MyScript[] myScripts = FindObjectsOfType<MyScript>();
foreach (MyScript myScript in myScripts) {
    print(myScript.myName + "/" + myScript.visible);
}
```

Comment: thanks Nic, I understand the part you explained. My challenge is to access variables in a script attached to a dynamically created GameObject, let me know if you have an idea on how to do that. (see the code i've just posted) cheers