# How can I use GetComponent<"type">() with a parameter?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to write a function that grabs a component based on a parameter.

I tried to use string, then GetType and it didn't work.

I tried using MonoBehaviour, but it didn't work. My current version is below.  What am I missing?

```
void move(MonoBehaviour co){
            Touch screentouch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(screentouch.position);
            if (screentouch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hitInfo))
                {
                    if (hitInfo.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<co>() != null)
                    {
                        set = true;

                    }
                }
}
```

Comment: You can't use an argument as a generic type parameter .. this shouldn't even compile at all ...

Comment: A generic parameter needs to be compile-time resolved (it can itself be a generic type; thus `GetComponent<co>()` will not even compile). Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/33906910/2864740 solve the issue relating to dynamic types / string names?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access dynamically added Component in Unity3d C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906741/access-dynamically-added-component-in-unity3d-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`GetComponent<T>`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) is a so called [**generic**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods) method.

The generic type parameter `T` needs to be a compile time constant **type** like e.g.

```
Renderer renderer = someGameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>();
```

will return an instance of type `Renderer`.

```
var something = someGameObject.GetComponent<ISomeInterface>();
```

will return an instance of type `ISomeInterface`.

---

The other overloads both `GetComponent(Type type)` and `GetComponent(string typeName)` both return the most basic type [`Component`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.html) and in order to properly work with it you have to type cast the result afterwards.

Same example would look like e.g.

```
Renderer renderer = (Renderer) someGameObject.GetComponent(typeof(Renderer));
```

or

```
Renderer renderer = (Renderer) someGameObject.GetComponent("Renderer");
```

---

So in your case you either know the type you are looking for and should pass that one in or if you want you can make your own method also generic and do

```
void move<T>()
{
    Touch screentouch = Input.GetTouch(0);
    Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(screentouch.position);
    if (screentouch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
    {
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hitInfo))
        {
            if (hitInfo.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<T>())
            {
                set = true;
            }
        }
   }
}
```